# Why do I get "no method named `join` found for type `[usize]` in the current scope"?

Tags: rust

```
fn example(books: Vec<usize>, n_books: usize) {
    let fbooks = books[0..n_books].join(" ");
}
```

```
error[E0599]: no method named `join` found for type `[usize]` in the current scope
 --> src/lib.rs:2:36
  |
2 |     let fbooks = books[0..n_books].join(" ");
  |                                    ^^^^ method not found in `[usize]`
```

I tried mapping `usize` to `String`, collecting into `Vec` and some more random stuff. I don't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR:
Since `map()` transforms one iterator into another iterator, you should provide an iterator first.
Try [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=4fb295645a813a02c87901ad799c27d1):

```
fn example(books: Vec<usize>, n_books: usize) -> String {
    books[0..n_books]
        .iter()
        .map(|u| u.to_string())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        .join(" ")
}
fn main() {
    let books: Vec<usize> = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let n_books: usize = 2;
    let result = example(books, n_books);
    println!("{}", result); //"1 2"
}
```

---

Notes:
You should not `join` the `usize` vector items with `&str` type.  You need to convert `usize` to string first then join it:

```
map(|u| u.to_string())
```

The standard library's `join` is defined only for slices, so the following code works:

```
let books: &[_] = &["1", "2", "3"];
let n_books: usize = 2;
let result = books[0..n_books].join(" ");
println!("{}", result); // "1 2"
```

---

**Edit:**
From your comment:

> What's the difference using `take(n)` or a subscript operator (re-slicing  `books[0..n_books]`)

**A slice is a type composed of a length and a pointer to a memory.**
You may use `.take(n_books)` instead of re-slicing, which is an iterator that only iterates over the first `n` iterations of `iter`, try [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=efcacc58b7b47ad44a1ce35689a15036):

```
    let books: Vec<usize> = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let n_books: usize = 2;
    let result = books
        .iter()
        .take(n_books)
        .map(|u| u.to_string())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        .join(" ");

    println!("{}", result); //"1 2"
```

Comment: When I only add the `map`:

"error[E0599]: no method named `map` found for type `[usize]` in the current scope"
  
Your answer works, but I don't know what's different about using `take` or a subscript operator